# Can't use keyboard extension in Spotlight after 8.3

Tags: swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios8.3

Since I updated my keyboard extension project to Swift 1.2 and my devices to iOS 8.3, I am no longer able to use my extension in Spotlight search. My extension is not in the list if I press and hold the "globe" key, and if it's the active keyboard when entering Spotlight the system keyboard is used instead. Other 3'rd party keyboards seems to work in Spotlight - and my own keyboard works in any other app I've tried it in (Notes, Mailbox, Safari etc). It used to work in Spotlight in all iOS 8.X versions up to 8.3.

Did anything change in 8.3 that I need to handle to be able to use my keyboard in Spotlight?

Comment: Have the exact same problem... Seems like I have to restart the device to get it to work (beyond idiotic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few device restarts it's back in Spotlight again. I guess it was a temporary fluke.