# Keyboard Extension not used in iPhone Search?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I have built a keyboard extension and it works as expected in most apps. However, it is not one of the keyboards rotated in iPhone Search bar:

[image]

Only the system keyboards are there. How can I enable my keyboard extension for the Search bar?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611505/cant-use-keyboard-extension-in-spotlight-after-8-3)